# Replace a string if it is different from the last one and the next one within a vector

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, character, outliers

I have a large dataset grouped by agent and date, the variable I want to clean is a string type variable. For instance, for the following dataset

```
agent_id<-c("1","1","1","2","2","2","2")
date<-c("2007-02-01","2007-02-02","2007-02-05","2000-05-01","2000-05-02","2000-05-10","2000-05-20")
office<-c("A","A","B","C","D","C","C")
mydata<-data.frame(agent_id,date,office)
```

I want to replace the outlier within a office vector if it is different from the last observation and the next observation within each agent_id. For instance, for agent_id=1, I don't want to replace anything. For agent_id=2, I want to replace "D" to "C" in office because I observe C both before and after. Is there any ways to do that with dplyr? Additionally, it would be better if I can define the cutoff to replace the outliears i.e. if I observe n same values before and n same values after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(agent_id) %>%
  mutate(
    office = replaceOutliers(x = office, window = 1)
  )
```

Where `replaceOutliers` is a custom function:

```
replaceOutliers <- function(x, window = 1, fixed_wind = FALSE) {

  x <- as.character(x)

  flag_Outl <- c(FALSE, sapply(2:(length(x) - 1), function(y) length(setdiff(x[pmax(1, y - window):pmax(1, y - 1)],
                                                     x[pmin(length(x) - 1, y + 1):pmin(length(x) - 1, y + window)])) == 0), FALSE)

  if (fixed_wind) {

  len_Lag <- sapply(1:length(x), function(y) length(office[pmax(1, y - window):pmax(1, y - 1)]))
  len_Lead <- sapply(1:length(x), function(y) length(office[pmin(length(x), y + 1):pmin(length(x), y + window)]))

  x <- sapply(1:length(flag_Outl), function(y) ifelse(flag_Outl[y] & len_Lag[y] == window & len_Lead[y] == window, x[y - 1], x[y]))

  }

  else x <- sapply(1:length(flag_Outl), function(y) ifelse(flag_Outl[y], x[y - 1], x[y]))

  return(x)

}
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   agent_id [2]
  agent_id date       office
  <fct>    <fct>      <chr> 
1 1        2007-02-01 A     
2 1        2007-02-02 A     
3 1        2007-02-05 C     
4 2        2000-05-01 C     
5 2        2000-05-02 C     
6 2        2000-05-10 C     
7 2        2000-05-20 C
```

As you will see I've included a `fixed_wind` parameter - basically you can decide whether you always need to have the exact number of observations before and after to consider something an outlier.

By default this is `FALSE`, and when you increase the `window` to 2 in your example, it'll still replace `D`, but if you put it to `TRUE`, it'll keep it as it is (as there is only 1 observation before it in the group):

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(agent_id) %>%
  mutate(
    office2 = replaceOutliers(x = office, window = 2),
    office3 = replaceOutliers(x = office, window = 2, fixed_wind = TRUE)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   agent_id [2]
  agent_id date       office office2 office3
  <fct>    <fct>      <fct>  <chr>   <chr>  
1 1        2007-02-01 A      A       A      
2 1        2007-02-02 A      A       A      
3 1        2007-02-05 C      C       C      
4 2        2000-05-01 C      C       C      
5 2        2000-05-02 D      C       D      
6 2        2000-05-10 C      C       C      
7 2        2000-05-20 C      C       C
```